# How do I compute the following probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have the following problem:

> Let $X,Y$ be two random variables which are indipendent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. I need to compute $\Bbb{P}\left(Y\leq \frac{X}{2}\right)$

Since they are uniformly distributed I know that their density maps are $\Bbb{1}_{[0,1]}$. Then I thought that $$\Bbb{P}\left(Y\leq \frac{X}{2}\right)=\Bbb{P}(2Y-X\leq 0)=F_{2Y-X}(0)$$. But I'm not sure if this works.

Could maybe someone help me?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in A\}=\iint_A f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y$

Comment: @Surb Ah so you mean that I first need to find $A$ geometrically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is correct, just compute the area of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:2y-x\leq0\}\cap[0,1]^2$.

If you want to use integration, you would have to compute $\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac{x}{2}}dydx$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure so I know this possibility but I wanted to compute it with integrals

Comment: I recently added the corresponding integrals.